# Trouble Deploying Rails App To Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ssh-keys

Below is are the steps I tried to deploy my rails app to heroku. However I'm getting "Your key with fingerprint is not authorized to access" my application.

1. Deleted all existing keys from ~/.ssh
2. $ heroku keys:clear
3. $ heroku create lunch-tr
4. Enter your Heroku credentials.
5. Email: adam.aahrens@gmail.com
6. Password (typing will be hidden):
7. Could not find an existing public key.
8. Would you like to generate one? [Yn] Y
9. Generating new SSH public key.
10. Uploading SSH public key /.ssh/id_rsa.pub... done
11. Creating lunch-tr... done, stack is cedar
12. http://lunch-tr.herokuapp.com/ | git@heroku.com:lunch-tr.git Git remote heroku added
13. $ git remote -v
14. heroku  git@heroku.com:lunch-tr.git (fetch) heroku  git@heroku.com:lunch-tr.git (push)
15. $ git push heroku master

    !  Your key with fingerprint 2f:0b:2c:e9:95:b4:52:af:dc:db:9c:57:e3:f2:57:7f is not authorized to access lunch-tr. fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Not sure what else I should try I'm running out of ideas. Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ssh-add` command, this adds private key identities to the authentication agent.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem.

Comment: Type `man ssh-add` in terminal to know your options, but when i have the same problem just `ssh-add` (without any options) helped me.